# Un-make folder git repository

Tags: git, github

I have accidentally made one of my folders a git repository by running `git init`. How I can reverse this process.

I am running windows ten and have git installed.

Comment: Delete the `.git` folder there. Note, unless you have a backup of it it is a irreversible action, so make sure you delete the *right* `.git` folder.

Comment: I cannot see the git folder, do I have to show hidden folders? I thought this was only a mac thing

Comment: No, hidden folders is absolutely a Windows thing as well. Though, depending on how the .git folder was created, sometimes it is hidden, sometimes it is not (has been my experience).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+init

Answer (score 4):

Just delete the .git folder in the root of your directory.

If you can't see it, check the "display hidden folders" in your windows directory settings

Comment: Sorry, how do I display hidden folders, I can't find the option (I'm new to windows from mac)

Comment: @AlexHawking https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLvHzL12028